# Shop page Infinite scrolling not working - Elementor

Tags: wordpress, archive, infinite-scroll, elementor

My website is experiencing infinite loading problems. I'm using Elementor builder to create a custom shop page, which worked fine at first but then the infinite scrolling feature stopped working.

The console displays an error.

[image: Console error]

I tried reactivating all plugins and looking for problems, but nothing worked. I also attempted to use Astra infinite scroll, but only the "load more" feature appears to be functional.

Could anyone please help me resolve this issue? I would appreciate any guidance you can provide. I would prefer not to install any additional plugins to solve the problem. Thank you.